# How use swagger generated "javascript-closure-angular-client" with AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm newb to swagger , I have generated `javascript-closure-angular-client` from [swagger-editor](https://editor.swagger.io/).

I want to used `javascript-closure-angular-client` in my AnuglarJS project. But I can't find any explanation for how to use it with AnuglarJS project.

Can anyone guide me for how to used `javascript-closure-angular-client` with AnuglarJS project?

Answer (score -1):

### I recommend you use `swagger-js-codegen`

Repository: https://github.com/wcandillon/swagger-js-codegen

And in this repository I explain how to generate the client in this case called clientAngularSwagger.js:
https://github.com/CayetanoHerreraLuisRicardo/swagger-angularjs-client

### The next step would be:

To add it to your AngularJS project, do the following:

- Add the generated file in the project for example:

  ```
   <script src="js/models/clientAngularSwagger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```
- Inject factory to controller

  ```
   angular.module('App').controller('test', function ($scope, clientSwagger) {
      ....
   }
  ```
- and finally do requests to the web service in test controller

  ```
   //clienSwagger object
   $scope.swaggerObject = new clientSwagger("APIurl",false); //the parameter "APIurl" is optional, because in the clientSwagger factory is defined

   //paramether to send
   $scope.parameters = [];
   $scope.parameters["authorization"]="Bearer xxxxxxxx";
   $scope.parameters["xparameter"]="xxxx";
   $scope.data = [];

   //request function  http
   $scope.BBBObject.herefunctionname($scope.parameters).then(function(res) 
   {
     $scope.data= res.data;
   }, function(e) {
      console.log(e);
   });
  ```